# When webpack compiles less, why it ignore `\`?

Tags: css, less, webpack

My less code:

[less code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2a63.jpg)

This is css code after compiled:

[css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AERhy.jpg)

Could u tell me what happened on compile? Why `\` ismissing???

Less code in online is true,but in the webpack after compiling,it would ignore `\`.
I think less-loadd filter `\`.

**This is less code:**

```css
a {
   &:after {
      content: "\A";
      white-space: pre;
    }
  }
```

**This is compiled css code:**

```css
a:after {
    content: "A";
    white-space: pre;
  }
```

Comment: Less won't do that. Something else that is involved in your compilation (and/or minification) process could be doing it. You can check your code online [here](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22a%7B%5Cn%20%20display%3A%20inline%3B%5Cn%20%20%26%3Aafter%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20content%3A%20'%5C%5CA'%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20white-space%3A%20pre%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: Think u for your suggestion.In online less is true for compiled,but in webpack,it really ignores `.I think less-loader will filter `\`.